# tcsh : Remapping keybindings

Tags: linux, terminal, tcsh

I want to set ALT + BACKSPACE as key for deleting word by word on tcsh terminal.

```
bindkey -b "M-^?" backward-delete-word
getting this error : Bad key spec M-^?
```

Doesn't seem to be working. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it without quotes:

```
bindkey -b M-^? backward-delete-word
```

Why is this? Because tcsh uses an old ad-hoc parser from the 70s with a long list of exceptions and unexpected behaviours like this. To quote the original author Bill Joy: "I didn't really know what I was doing at the time"  This is actually a good example of why people generally advice to avoid (t)csh if you can.

Comment: I had tried without comment too, but the key ALT + BACKSPACE doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's probably a problem with your terminal emulator @pradeep; what does it show if you press Control+v and the alt+BS? That should show the keycodes that get sent to tcsh.

Comment: alt + BS shows nothing. When I press ctrl+v and ctrl + BS, I see ^H. I guess I cannot use ALT key for key binding.

Comment: That's probably something you can configure in your terminal emulator @pradeep; Alt+key is actually "Escape character + key" (two characters are sent); but some terminal emulators use Alt-keys for other functionality. For example for xterm you can set `XTerm.vt100.metaSendsEscape: true`. Try searching for "alt key + [terminal emulator name]" and you should probably find an answer :-)

Comment: My terminal emulator is mater-terminal, didn't find any information on searching about escape characters n mate terminal.